# Troubleshooting Narrow Learning Outcomes in Integrated CNN-LSTM Model for Sequence Prediction

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, lstm

I've been experimenting with creating somewhat complex models. My current focus is on ensuring consistent results across runs, so I'm seeking advice from those with relevant experience.

The model architecture is designed to first extract features from the input sequences using CNN layers with kernels of various sizes (implemented in a custom class ConvMultikernelMaxLearner), and then to process these features temporally using an LSTM layer (implemented in a custom class LSTMLearner).

```
class ConvMultikernelMaxLearner(nn.Module):
    """여러 크기의 커널로 다양한 관점으로 특징을 추출하는 Conv/MaxPooling 학습자"""
    def __init__(self):
        super(ConvMultikernelMaxLearner, self).__init__()

        self.seq1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv1d(in_channels=1, out_channels=16, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(num_features=16),  # Apply batch normalization
            nn.SiLU(),  # Activation function follows BN
            nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=2),  # length n/2
            
            nn.Conv1d(in_channels=16, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(num_features=32),  # Apply batch normalization
            nn.SiLU(),  # Activation function follows BN
            nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=2),  # length n/4
            
            nn.Conv1d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(num_features=64),  # Apply batch normalization
            nn.SiLU(),  # Activation function follows BN
            nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=2),  # length n/8
        )
        
        ModelShaper.report_shape(self.seq1, (32, 1, 144))
        
        self.seq2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv1d(in_channels=1, out_channels=16, kernel_size=5, padding=2),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(num_features=16),  # Apply batch normalization
            nn.SiLU(),  # Activation function follows BN
            nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=2),  # length n/2
            
            nn.Conv1d(in_channels=16, out_channels=32, kernel_size=5, padding=2),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(num_features=32),  # Apply batch normalization
            nn.SiLU(),  # Activation function follows BN
            nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=2),  # length n/4
            
            nn.Conv1d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=5, padding=2),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(num_features=64),  # Apply batch normalization
            nn.SiLU(),  # Activation function follows BN
            nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=2),  # length n/8
        )
        
        ModelShaper.report_shape(self.seq2, (32, 1, 144))
        
        self.modules = nn.ModuleList([self.seq1, self.seq2])
        
    def forward(self, x):
        """x는 타임스텝이 8배수인 시퀀스 데이터"""
        y1 = self.seq1(x)
        y2 = self.seq2(x)
        return torch.cat((y1, y2), dim=1)
```

This is Conv Layer.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class LSTMLearner(nn.Module):
    """
    LSTM learner layer that learns time series based on features created from the CNN layer,
    arranged in parallel to form (timesteps, all features).
    """
    def __init__(self, timesteps: int, features: int):
        super(LSTMLearner, self).__init__()
        
        hidden_size = 128
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=features,
                            hidden_size=hidden_size,
                            num_layers=5,
                            batch_first=True,
                            dropout=0.2)
        
        self.end_layer = nn.Sequential(
            nn.BatchNorm1d(hidden_size),
            nn.Linear(hidden_size, 72),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(72),
            nn.SiLU(),
            nn.Linear(72, 36),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(36),
            nn.SiLU(),
            nn.Linear(36, 18),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(18),
            nn.SiLU(),
            nn.Linear(18, 2)
        )
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x, (hn, cn) = self.lstm(x)
        return self.end_layer(hn[-1])


class IntegratedModelEpsilon(nn.Module):
    """
    Learns an n*2 sequence created by combining price and volume sequences.
    """
    def __init__(self, timesteps: int, features: int):
        super(IntegratedModelEpsilon, self).__init__()
        
        self.trade_max = ConvMultikernelMaxLearner()
        self.volume_max = ConvMultikernelMaxLearner()
        
        self.lstm = LSTMLearner(timesteps//8, 256)
        
    def forward(self, trade, volume):
        trade_max = self.trade_max(trade)
        volume_max = self.volume_max(volume)
        
        xx = torch.cat((trade_max, volume_max), dim=1).transpose(1, 2)
        return self.lstm(xx)
```

The purpose of transpose(1, 2) is to convert the data from (batch, number of conv features, timesteps) to (batch, timesteps, number of conv features), preparing it for the LSTM layer.

After constructing this model and initiating training, I observed that the learning results are consistently output within a very narrow scope, which I found unusual. This isn't my first experience with such an issue.

Could there be a fundamental flaw in how I'm constructing the model? Any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue and how to address it?